# Problem with Fourier transform

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdhpu.png]

How to define a top hat function with plot also at opening and closing value?
and

How to plot a Fourier transform of the function?

Comment: `UnitBox[x/(2 Omega)]`, `FourierTransform[UnitBox[x/(2 Omega)], x, \[Xi]]`, and `Plot`?

Comment: Hi Ashwin and welcome to Mma.SE! Your question needs more from your side, it's hard to understand. Here its considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) to explain better what you need. Also, please take the [tour], it will help you understand the site. If  you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) it will inspire great answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[f, F]
```

As [recommended](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174559/how-to-give-input-for-a-top-hat-function-and-find-its-fourier-transform-also-ho#comment458272_174559) by [`Henrik Schumacher`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178/henrik-schumacher) you can use [`UnitBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitBox.html)

```
F[ω_, Ω_: 1] := UnitBox[ω/(2 Ω)];

f[t_, Ω_: 1] = FourierTransform[F[ω, Ω], ω, t] // Simplify[#, Ω > 0] &

(* Sqrt[2/π] Ω Sinc[t Ω] *)
```

Note that [`Sinc[x]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sinc.html) is preferable to `Sin[x]/x` since it is defined for `x == 0` without having to take the [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html)

```
Sin[x]/x /. x -> 0
```

[image]

```
Limit[Sin[x]/x, x -> 0] == Sinc[0] == 1

(* True *)
```

You could also use [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html)

```
F[ω_, Ω_: 1] := UnitStep[ω + Ω] - UnitStep[ω - Ω]

Show[plt = Plot[F[ω], {ω, -1.2, 1.2}, Exclusions -> None],
 Ticks -> {AbsoluteOptions[plt, Ticks][[1, -1, 1]] /.
    {x_?NumericQ, xl_?NumericQ, rest___} :> {x, Ω*Rationalize[xl], rest}, 
   Automatic},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {ω, Subscript[Overscript[f, "~"], Ω]})]
```

[image]

```
f[t_, Ω_: 1] = FourierTransform[F[ω, Ω], ω, t] /. Sin[x_] :> x Sinc[x]

(* Sqrt[2/π] Ω Sinc[t Ω] *)

Plot[f[t], {t, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {t, Subscript[f, Ω][t]}),
 Ticks -> {{{Pi, Pi/Ω}}, {{f[0], f[0, Ω]}}}]
```

[image]